# How to insert an ID from an HTML document into a VAR function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, var, typeid

Im trying to make an 'online' (HTML document) file that has an input to solve math, and I need a way to type in the numbers, and insert a 'solve me' button.  I have the button, and the form by ID and class as well.

This is what I inserted into a "try it" prompt box through w3schools.com site, tried looking almost everywhere within that site to try to input it in.

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>

<script>
    var A = 1;
    var ele = document.getElementById('A');
    var y = 2;
    var z = A + y;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
</script>
```

Is there a way to do this?  And thank you guys for your help!

Comment: So, you want a button with "solve me" text to display when you input number into an input?

Comment: Do you mean Java (as the title says) or Javascript?  If Java, then you could do it all server side with a simple JSP page.  Yet, this could all be done client side too with a small bit of javascript. Please clarify your question.

Comment: my bad guys, Im not the greatest at asking questions...  But I respect your critique.  I have the button planned, but I needed a variable var function to do inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="A"/>
<input id="B"/>
<div id="demo"></div>
<button onclick="add();">ADD</button>
<script>
function add () {
    var A = document.getElementById('A').value *1;
    var B = document.getElementById('B').value *1;
    var z = A + B;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you, here you need to use input to have a user editable field,a div as you guessed to display your answer and button which triggers some logic.

Comment: That helped me a lot bud.  May I ask that is there a setup of radio buttons I can try that solves for specific variables?

Comment: are the radio buttons needed to choose different operations to perform on the input ?

Comment: I have also experienced a problem @Alok I tried putting it all into a table where I have the "Please type input a" then on the right is the prompt box to type in.  The problem is whenever I try to input the numbers, nothing shows, var z isnt showing.  Im trying to attach the problem into the comments but i cant...
The whole purpose is a clean look like a form.